# Modeling a domain as a GADT type and providing do-sugar for it

Tags: haskell, gadt

Assume we'd like to build a type that represents operations typical for, let's say, a lock-free algorithm:

```hs
newtype IntPtr = IntPtr { ptr :: Int } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Op r where 
  OpRead :: IntPtr -> Op Int
  OpWrite :: IntPtr -> Int -> Op ()

  OpCAS :: IntPtr -> Int -> Int -> Op Bool
```

Ideally, we'd like to represent some algorithms within this model using a convenient `do`-notation, like (assuming corresponding `read = OpRead` and `cas = OpCAS` for aesthetic reasons) the following almost literal translation of the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap#Example_application:_atomic_adder):

```hs
import Prelude hiding (read)
import Control.Monad.Loops

add :: IntPtr -> Int -> Op Int
add p a = snd <$> do
  iterateUntil fst $ do
    value <- read p
    success <- cas p value (value + a)
    pure (success, value + a)
```

How could we achieve that? Let's add a couple more constructors to `Op` to represent pure injected values and the monadic bind:

```hs
  OpPure :: a -> Op a
  OpBind :: Op a -> (a -> Op b) -> Op b
```

So let's try to write a `Functor` instance. `OpPure` and `OpBind` is easy, being, for instance:

```hs
instance Functor Op where
  fmap f (OpPure x) = OpPure (f x)
```

But the constructors that specify the GADT type start smelling bad:

```hs
  fmap f (OpRead ptr) = do
    val <- OpRead ptr
    pure $ f val
```

Here we assume we'll write the `Monad` instance later on anyway to avoid ugly nested `OpBind`s.

Is this the right way to handle such types, or is my design just terribly wrong, this being a sign of it?

Comment: Are you familiar with free monads?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson let's say I'm just familiar with their existence. I'd be glad if this task at hand would be a good case to learn them.

Comment: Yep! You've actually almost invented `Free`. I'll write up an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This style of using `do`-notation to build a syntax tree that'll be interpreted later is modelled by the *free monad*. (I'm actually going to demonstrate what's known as the *freer* or *operational* monad, because it's closer to what you have so far.)

Your original `Op` datatype - without `OpPure` and `OpBind` - represents a set of atomic typed instructions (namely `read`, `write` and `cas`). In an imperative language a program is basically a list of instructions, so let's design a datatype which represents a list of `Op`s.

One idea might be to use an actual list, ie `type Program r = [Op r]`. Clearly that won't do as it constrains every instruction in the program to have the same return type, which would not make for a very useful programming language.

The key insight is that in any reasonable operational semantics of an interpreted imperative language, control flow doesn't proceed past an instruction until the interpreter has computed a return value for that instruction. That is, the *n*th instruction of a program depends in general on the results of instructions 0 to *n*-1. We can model this using continuation passing style.

```
data Program a where
    Return :: a -> Program a
    Step :: Op r -> (r -> Program a) -> Program a
```

A `Program` is a kind of list of instructions: it's either an empty program which returns a single value, or it's a single instruction followed by a list of instructions. The function inside the `Step` constructor means that the interpreter running the `Program` has to come up with an `r` value before it can resume interpreting the rest of the program. So sequentiality is ensured by the type.

To build your atomic programs `read`, `write` and `cas`, you need to put them in a singleton list. This involves putting the relevant instruction in the `Step` constructor, and passing a no-op continuation.

```
lift :: Op a -> Program a
lift i = Step i Return

read ptr = lift (OpRead ptr)
write ptr val = lift (OpWrite ptr val)
cas ptr cmp val = lift (OpCas ptr cmp val)
```

`Program` differs from your tweaked `Op` in that at each `Step` there's only ever one instruction. `OpBind`'s left argument was potentially a whole tree of `Op`s. This would've allowed you to distinguish differently-associated `>>=`s, breaking the monad associativity law.

You can make `Program` a monad.

```
instance Monad Program where
    return = Return
    Return x >>= f = f x
    Step i k >>= f = Step i ((>>= f) . k)
```

`>>=` basically performs list concatenation - it walks to the end of the list (by composing recursive calls to itself under the `Step` continuations) and grafts on a new tail. This makes sense - it corresponds to the intutitive "run this program, then run that program" semantics of `>>=`.

---

Noting that `Program`'s `Monad` instance doesn't depend on `Op`, an obvious generalisation is to parameterise the type of instruction and make `Program` into a list of any old instruction set.

```
data Program i a where
    Return :: a -> Program i a
    Step :: i r -> (r -> Program i a) -> Program a

instance Monad (Program i) where
    -- implementation is exactly the same
```

So `Program i` is a monad for free, no matter what `i` is. This version of `Program` is a rather general tool for modelling imperative languages.

Comment: That's really beautiful, thanks! Interestingly, once a particular more or less abstract technique is used to solve some specific problem, it becomes way more obvious and clear.